# How can I get to identify the storage ID of authenticated finger through reflection in android

Tags: java, android, android-fingerprint-api

I am a novice developer trying to creating an android app to be used by different users on one single device. I intend to use fingerprint authentication to quickly identify the different users.

So I have registered the different users fingerprints on the device. Since I am able to get the list of fingerprint storage IDs of each fingerprint through reflection (though not recommended nor supported). Below is the working code for getting all the fingerprint ids on the device:

```
  public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {

 try {
            Method method = FingerprintManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getEnrolledFingerprints");
            Object obj = method.invoke(mFingerprintManager);
            if (obj != null) {
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.hardware.fingerprint.Fingerprint");
                Method getFingerId = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getFingerId");
                for (int i = 0; i < ((List) obj).size(); i++) {
                    Object item = ((List) obj).get(i);
                    if (null == item) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "fingerId: " + getFingerId.invoke(item));
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

I have been stuck at the point of getting the actual ID of the fingerprint that has been authenticated from the fingerprint authentication results. Below is what I have tried.

```
 public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {


        try {
            Field field = result.getClass().getDeclaredField("mFingerprint");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object fingerPrint = field.get(result);

            if (fingerPrint == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "name: fingerPrint is null");
        }
            Class<?> clzz = Class.forName("android.hardware.fingerprint.Fingerprint");
            Method getName = clzz.getDeclaredMethod("getName");
            Method getFingerId = clzz.getDeclaredMethod("getFingerId");
            Method getGroupId = clzz.getDeclaredMethod("getGroupId");
            Method getDeviceId = clzz.getDeclaredMethod("getDeviceId");

            CharSequence name = (CharSequence) getName.invoke(fingerPrint);
            int fingerId = (int) getFingerId.invoke(fingerPrint);
            int groupId = (int) getGroupId.invoke(fingerPrint);
            long deviceId = (long) getDeviceId.invoke(fingerPrint);

            Log.d(TAG, "name: " + name);
            Log.d(TAG, "fingerId: " + fingerId);
            Log.d(TAG, "groupId: " + groupId);
            Log.d(TAG, "deviceId: " + deviceId);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

I get this error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: null receiver
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.example.android.fingerprintdialog.FingerprintUiHelper.onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintUiHelper.java:130)
```

On this line of code:

```
CharSequence name = (CharSequence) getName.invoke(fingerPrint);
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using reflection?  It seems this adds additional complexity.  Why dont you first try this without reflection to see if you can get this working.

Comment: Note that your code will fail on newer versions of Android, as Android is blocking your form of reflection. And, some of your code that you are trying to use via reflection simply no longer exists on newer versions of Android.

Comment: Yes I know. The app is for in-house use and not intended for distribution in any way.

Comment: Note also that FingerprintManager has been deprecated in API 28.  It is replaced by BiometricManager: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricManager

Comment: @EJK Reflection is the only way of  achieving this goal

Comment: @timk - That might be the case, but could you please explain why it is the only way?  What exactly does not work when call these methods directly?

Comment: @EJK - The api only supports app notification of success or failure on fingerprint scan. With reflection i am able to access hidden functions that can give you the ID of the scanned finger

Comment: You haven't mentioned what you are running this on. The `getName` method no longer exists in Android 10. It _may_ exist in earlier Android versions. You'll probably have to find some specific device where this is known to work, and then refrain from updating it to a newer Android version. Also keep in mind that Android devices typically have pretty a pretty low maximum number of fingerprints that you can have enrolled, since the fingerprint feature is really only meant to be used by the device owner.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the feedback. I am using android 8.0